# ngx-siema how to set interval

Tags: javascript, angular, siema

I am trying to mimic an autoplay setting for **[ngx-siema](https://github.com/lexzhukov/ngx-siema)** , using:

`setInterval(() => mySiema.next(), 1000)`

as described **[here](https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/MbPbLM)**.

How can I do that? Here is my setup:

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private ngxSiemaService: NgxSiemaService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    options: NgxSiemaOptions = {
        selector: ".siema",
        duration: 1000,
        loop: true
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using the provided service (which provides the init function), I added a `next()` method with a desired `setInterval`, as follows:

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private ngxSiemaService: NgxSiemaService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.next();
    }

    options: NgxSiemaOptions = {
        selector: ".siema",
        duration: 1000,
        loop: true
    };

    next() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.ngxSiemaService.next(1);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```